# Loop exactly N! times for the permutation logic?

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

The following code basically get the permutation of a string. So I expected the time complexity to be `O(N!)`.
Running the following code with parameter "abc" will show it loops 36 instead of `3!` times when not using the HashSet to check if the string is already added.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    generated = new HashSet<string>();
    var test = getA(args[0]);
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var s in test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}:{s}");
        i++;
    }
}

static HashSet<string> generated;
private static IEnumerable<string> getA(string v)
{
    if (v.Length <= 1)
    {
        yield return v;
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
        {
            var c = v[i];
            var s = v.Remove(i, 1);
            Console.WriteLine($"  i:{i} v:{v} c:{c} s:{s}");
            foreach (var t in getA(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"      t:{t}");
                for (var k = 0; k < t.Length; k++)
                {
                    if (c != t[k])
                    {
                        var result = t.Insert(k, c.ToString());
                        //if (!generated.Contains(result))
                        {
                            generated.Add(result);
                            yield return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //if (!generated.Contains(t + c))
                {
                    generated.Add(t + c);
                    yield return t + c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Big O refers to the *asymptotic complexity* as the variables approach infinity.

It's not a measure of the *exact number* of operations that will be performed.

As you continually increase the input size and get closer to infinity the actual number of operations performed will continually get closer to "N!".